# Clean IndexedDB when tab is closing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, indexeddb, session-storage

I need to keep some data in `indexedDB` instead on `sessionStorage` as amount of data is more than 5 MB.

I'm confused about cleanup strategy as in case of page reload or navigation to the other page I need this data to be kept, but if user closes browser tab I'd like to remove it to save place.

How can I do that? Need it to be working at least in Chrome.

Comment: My knowledge here is a bit rusty but you can bind to the unload or beforeunload events fired on the window. The behavior in browsers varies, and unfortunately I think these events get fired always, when tab closed and page refreshed. Perhaps a better strategy, is on load, cleanup the old data. Is it ok to leave it there indefinitely?

Comment: @Josh, how can I understand that some data is not used? There can be multiple tabs and I don't want to remove data of neighbour tab.

Comment: I do not believe you have any indicator within indexedDB regarding which tab was responsible for storing the data. Perhaps you can invent a way to do this yourself such as by storing an extra property that uniquely identifies each tab.

Answer (score 5):

You can store an indicator in the session storage, then delete the database if that value does not exist.

```js
(async() =>
{
  if (!sessionStorage.getItem('just-a-placeholder'))
  {
    indexedDB.deleteDatabase('temp');
    sessionStorage.setItem('just-a-placeholder', true);
  }

  const databases = await indexedDB.databases();
  console.log(databases.find(db => db.name === 'temp') !== undefined)
  await indexedDB.open('temp');
})();
```

Sadly StackOverflow does not run snippets in a way I could show this here but here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/08wzf59d/) to show it in action.

Comment: My question is: _When I should delete data from indexedDB?_ Can't understand how you answer relates to it.

Comment: The database will be removed when the `sessionStorage` is cleared aka when the user closes the browser, since your question was fundamentally asking for more storage on the `sessionStorage` object.

Comment: No as indexedDB is a persistent storage.